Регулярное выражение для цифр с ограниченной длиной
Помогите составить регулярное выражение

Только цифры
Длина 11 цифр
Если две первые цифры 37, то длина может быть 11 или 12


начинай делать, поможем. Пока что ты просишь сделать задание вместо тебя.

Прямо вот по шагам и делайте. Проще некуда. 3-й шаг будет не такой элементарный, но через "или" этот вариант легко добавляется.

Господи. Маска - либо 11 любых цифр, либо 37+10 любых цифр. Просто и плоско.

Сделал такую:
^[0-9]{11}$|^(37){12}$
Но она не работает на условии 37

@2ndTry Ваши попытки нужно прямо в вопросе писать. Там просто нужно было (37)[0-9]{10}, потому что не 37 же должно было 12 раз повторяться, а 37 один раз, а потом произвольные цифры ещё 10 раз.

import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^(37\d{9}|37\d{10}|\d{11})$')


Первый шаблон не нужен, третий его покрывает. А вообще не решайте простые задачи за кого-то, человек их должен сам решать, чтобы чему-то научиться. Если он даже не сделал никаких попыток, то решать за него задачу не нужно.
